Cilium operator creating heartbeat annotation after job terminates
I am facing a weird issue, where the garbage collection of Cilium identities is very slow for kubernetes jobs. In particular, I am using the keda ScaledJob custom resource type.
After the ScaledJob terminates, the corresponding cilium identities are sometimes not cleaned up for 1-2 hours. Is this a bug or is this normal behaviour?
What is particularly weird, is that the Cilium identities sometimes show a very recent heartbeat annotation, even though the corresponding pods (the pod of the ScaledJob) has been terminated 1h ago.
Does anyone understand the cilium operator's heartbeat implementation well enough, to explain how such an annotation can happen after a job is terminated?
Cilium version: v1.14.3
